# centos7: run .sh script from php (sudo)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, sudo

i want to run a script from php like root user

so in php i use this

```
 $output = shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/sh  /var/www/kill.sh');
 echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

now in centos7 i run **vim /etc/sudoers** and at the end of the file i pasted this

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL 
then i restart: systemctl restart httpd
```

but is not working

> also i tried this: **shell_exec('ls')** it works and **shell_exec('sudo ls')**
>   is not working